# Can I display a message in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question related to SQL.

Can I display a custom message in MySQL phpMyAdmin, something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
PRINT 'The message that I want to write!';
```

I tried to do it with PRINT syntax, because I found something like that, but it doesn't work. Do you have some ideas?

Comment: `SELECT 'PRINT' FROM table_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the text in the `SELECT` statement

```
SELECT *, 'PRINT' FROM foo;
```

[image]

If you're wanting to print a long message, and want a different column name, simply use an alias by using `AS`.

```
SELECT *, 'The message i want to print' AS msg FROM foo;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can simulate a print with the select statement like this:

```
SELECT 'some text'
```

Comment: I love the idea of stimulating a print!

Answer (score 0):

You can't `PRINT` but you can simulate it using:

```
SELECT 'The message that I want to write!' as '';
```

So you're selecting a string value, with an empty column heading, from no table in particular.